# How to find all the tree leaves of an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trees

I'd like to better understand what mathematica is doing during simplification, so I tried `expression //TreeForm //TreeLeaves` to see what it's picking up on.

Except that mathematica threw an error. Why is this?

Comment: From the documentation "In TreeLeaves[tree], tree must be a valid Tree object".

Comment: Isn't that what TreeForm is?

Comment: `Head@TreeForm@expression` -> `TreeForm`. Try `expression // ExpressionTree // TreeLeaves`

Comment: For versions prior to v12.3: `Level[expr, {-1}]` gives leaves of the expression `expr`.

Comment: @Syed Do you know why did they change that?

Comment: No idea, but someone from WRI would know. I am on 12.2 and don't have `TreePlot` and all these new functions, so I was intrigued by the question.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, that works, but doesn't match LeafCount. For example, take the espression ```Sqrt[y/x]/2```. ```//ExpressionTree // TreeLeaves //Dimensions``` evaluates to 5, whereas ```//Leafcount``` evaluates to 13. (on version 12.3)

Comment: Check the "Properties and Relations" section in the documentation for `LeafCount`.